# integral of $\int5\sec(4x)\tan(4x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was thinking about using $u$-substitution, so I did here's what I got
$$ \int5\sec(4x)\tan(4x)\,dx =\int\sec(u)\tan(u)(4)\,du= \frac{5}{4} \int \sec(u)\tan(u)\,du= \frac{5}{4} \sec(4x) + C.$$

Thanks

Comment: Which mistake are you talking about?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the final answer i got

Comment: My book says that this is wrong

Comment: If you differentiate the answer, you reach at $80\sec(4x)\tan(4x)$

Comment: You messed up in the substitution, try again.

Comment: I think the easiest way to understand substitution is to "build" what you need in the differential term: $$dx = d(\tfrac14 4x)=\tfrac14\;d(4x)$$Now you can substitute $u$ for $4x$ everywhere:$$\int 5\sec 4x\tan 4x\; dx=\int 5\sec 4x\tan 4x\cdot \tfrac14\; d(4x)$$ $$=\int 5\sec u\tan u\cdot \tfrac14\; du$$ $$=\int \tfrac54 \sec u\tan u \; du$$

Answer (score 2):

Your substitution was wrong. Letting $4x=u$ then $4dx=du$ or $dx=du/4$.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized myself :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do $4x=u$, you have to do $4\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm du$ too. So, you get$$\int5\sec(4x)\tan(4x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac54\int\sec(4x)\tan(4x)4\,\mathrm dx)=\frac54\int\sec(u)\tan(u)\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: Yes I realized I made a simple error in arithmetic.

Comment: I aprreciate for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $\frac d{dx}(4x)=4$, $$\int5\sec(4x)\tan(4x)\,dx=5\cdot\frac14\int\sec(4x)\tan(4x)\cdot\frac{d(4x)}{dx}\,dx$$ so if $u=4x$ then $$\int5\sec(4x)\tan(4x)\,dx=\frac54\int\sec u\tan u\,du.$$